# Adding Ricardian Clause

Tags: smart-contract, abi, ricardian

I am new to eosio and so far I have been learning using EOS Studio.  I have come to the point where I would like to be able to write some Ricardian Clauses in the abi file but EOS Studio does not seem to want me to do that.

So I was wondering, is directly editing the abi file the way to go or is there a better way to handle this?

If editing the abi file directly is the way to go then a bonus question is why does EOS Studio stop me from doing this?

edit. I found that with eosio-init that a ricardian directory is created with a md file but when I make the project I always get

Warning, action  does not have a ricardian contract

Answer (score 0):

Just create ".clauses.md" along with the ".contracts.md" one. And place your ricardian clauses in it:

```
<h1 class="clause"> id text </h1>
body text
```